# Tomcat 7 with Netbeans 7.3 does not log

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, logging, netbeans

I've installed Netbeans 7.3.1 (the latestI think) on Windows 7, and the problem  I have is that Tomcat does not write anything to it's logs. The C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.34\logs is always empty.
I've added the CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE variables, and changed the paths in the logging.properties file to D:\logs (a folder I created), and still nothing.

The Apache Tomcat Log tab in Netbeans Output is also blank.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. What was the fix?

Comment: Moving to IntelliJ IDEA :) . Sad, but it helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to explicitly tell Tomcat what you want it to log. That is definitely why your Log tab is blank in netbeans.

For example, if I am running database call and I want to log errors then I would do something like this

```
try{

makeDatabaseCall();// Just a pseudo function
}catch(SQLException ex{

Logger.getLogger(CurrentClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Personal message about error", ex); 
}
```

The last line will attach my personal message to the top of the stack trace of that exception.

The other way to do it is inside a servlet simply call log("Message you want to log"); The log function is one of the GenericServlet class methods.

Comment: Of course, that's what I'm doing :). That is what I meant when saying it is not logging, that has no effect.

Comment: O I see. Thought you were looking for auto logging...If you see nothing in the Netbeans console when you know for sure that you are logging then maybe it's a bug. I'm using 7.3 which I downloaded maybe 2 months ago. If 7.3.1 is brand spanking new it might indeed be a bug. I'd send the problem to Netbeans. They respond pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it writing there?

I believe the normal Netbeans Tomcat setup points CATALINA_HOME at your install location and CATALINA_BASE at %APPDATA%\NetBeans$NBVER\apache-tomcat-$tomcatver_base. Check your configured server's settings under Servers on the Services tab of NetBeans. Your log files are probably going to the $CATALINA_BASE/log directory.

Can it write there?

Permissions under C:\Program Files\ are usually more restrictive unless you have changed permissions under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation or run as administrator. I wouldn't do that. I prefer the %APPDATA% $CATALINA_BASE approach and second to that, relaxing the permissions on the Tomcat folder.